# Image.createImage problem in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, image.createimage

I tried this on J2ME

```
try {
    Image immutableThumb = Image.createImage( temp, 0, temp.length);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

I hit this error: 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:`

How do I solve this?

Comment: If you include some more specific information, e.g. stack trace or exception message, it might be possible to provide an answer.

Comment: I think that the only way to help you is if you show us how did you get the temp array.

Answer (score 1):

Image.createImage() throws an IllegalArgumentException if the first argument is incorrectly formatted or otherwise cannot be decoded. (I'm assuming that temp is a byte[]).

http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createImage(byte[],%20int,%20int)

(This URL refuses to become a hyperlink for some reason (?))

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more details or more surrounding code, but my initial suspicion is that the file your are trying to load is in a format not supported by the device.

Answer (score 1):

Let us have a look at the docs: IllegalArgumentException is thrown

> if imageData is incorrectly formatted or otherwise cannot be decoded

So the possible reason can be either unsupported format of the image, or truncated data. Remember, you should pass entire file to that method, including all the headers. If you have doubts about the format, you'd better choose **PNG**, it must be supported anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with my MIDLET and the problem in my case was the HTTP header that comes along the JPEG image that I read from the socket's InputStream. And I solved it by finding the JPEG SOI marker that is identified by two bytes: `FFD8` in my byte array. Then when I find the location of the `FFD8` in my byte array, I trim the starting bytes that represent the HTTP header, and then I could call `createImage()` without any Exception being thrown...

You should check if this is the case with you. Just check is this true `(temp[0] == 0xFF && temp[1] == 0xD8)` and if it is not, trim the start of `temp` so you remove HTTP header or some other junk...

**P.S.** 
I presume that you are reading JPEG image, if not, look for the appropriate header in the `temp` array.

Also if this doesn't help, and you are reading JPEG image make sure that the array starts with `FFD8` and ends with `FFD9` (which is the EOI marker). And if it doesn't end with the EOI just trim the end like I explained for SOI...

**P.P.S**
And if you find that the data in `temp` is valid, then your platform cannot decode the JPEG images or the image in `temp` is to large for JPEG decoder.